# Background color doesn't cover the whole screen

Tags: android, xml

I have set the background color of gridview to yellow but the color is visible only to a few part and doesn't cover the whole screen.
I am posting my xml layout code below.The layout shows the background color only to a part of screen and not on whole of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#b5b5b5">
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="200"
    android:columnCount="7"
    android:background="#FDC80A"
    android:accessibilityLiveRegion="none"
    android:layoutMode="clipBounds"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:visibility="visible">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:text="CODE"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DATE"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PHONE"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EXP.DATE"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E-MAIL"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/exdate"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="REG.NO."
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/regno"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="REG.DATE"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/regdate"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VEH. TYPE"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_row="22"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_row="23"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VEH.MAKE"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_row="22"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_row="23"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MODEL"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_row="25"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_row="25"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_row="31"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="#5b5b5b"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried out your code. It looks good at my end. Do you have something weird in your AppTheme style?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout has many EditText

add `android:background="your_color"`
to your  all your EditText

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the background color of customview in coordinator layout to desired color and got it.